# how to disable layer in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I have some layers inside a LayerSwitcher.I want to show them but i would like to disable one of them, I mean it must be visible inside layerSwitcher but you will not be able to interact with it.
This is my LayerSwitcher:
For example i  would like to disable on yellow layers.
Here is part of my code to add layers

```
    stationsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: stationsSource,
        visible: true,
        title: "Estaciones",
        style: styleFunction,
    });
    tiffRaster = new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'PGA(gal)',
        // extent: [-180, -90, -180, 90],
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://url/geoserver/faml/wms',
            params: {
                'LAYERS': 'faml:' + f
            },
            ratio: 1,
            serverType: 'geoserver'
        })
    });

    map.addLayer(tiffRaster);
    map.addLayer(stationsLayer);
```

[layerSwitcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frT2L.png)

Answer (score -2):

```js
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  title: "OSM"
});
var stamenLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.Stamen({
    layer: "terrain",
    maxZoom: 18
  }),
  visible: false,
  title: "Stamen"
});
var baseLayerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
  layers: [osmLayer, stamenLayer]
})

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: document.getElementById("map"),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([8, 50]),
    zoom: 5
  })
});
map.setLayerGroup(baseLayerGroup);

const radioButtons = getAllRadioButtons();
for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
  radioButtons[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    baseLayerGroup.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
      layer.setVisible(layer.get("title") === target.value);
    });
  });
}

function getAllRadioButtons() {
  var arrInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  var arrRadio = [];
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrInput.length; i++) {
    if (arrInput[i].type == "radio") {
      arrRadio[j] = arrInput[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  return arrRadio;
}
```

```css
* {
       box-sizing: border-box;
     }


     body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }

     .grid-container {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: 20vw 80vw;
       grid-template-rows: 100vh;
     }

     .sidebar {
       margin-left: 15px;
     }

     .map {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.8.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.8.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-1">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>
        Base Layers
      </h2>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" value="OSM" name="base" checked>
        <label for="OSM">OpenStreetMap</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" value="Stamen" name="base">
        <label for="Stamen">Terrain</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-2">
    <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
tiffRaster.setVisible(false)
```

and

```
tiffRaster.setVisible(true)
```

should do it.

Comment: it works to check or uncheck the checkbox, I mean if its possible to show the checkBox with its title but you are not able to interact with it

Comment: Code snippet added.